# Is self retained within this Objective-C block?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

When I have a block in Objective-C that looks like this:

```
self.request = [[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:...

[self.longPollRequest setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"%@", self.request.responseString);
}];
```

will it retain `self` or explicitly retain `self.request`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As  the [Block Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1) says:

> In a reference-counted environment, by
> default when you reference an
> Objective-C object within a block, it
> is retained. This is true even if you
> simply reference an instance variable
> of the object. Object variables marked
> with the __block storage type
> modifier, however, are not retained.
>
> If you use a block within the implementation of a method, the rules
> for memory management of object
> instance variables are more subtle:
>
> If you access an instance variable by reference, self is
> retained;
>
> If you access an instance variable by
> value, the variable is retained.

you reference `self` in block, so `self` is retained.

Comment: You can avoid retaining `self` if you declare e.g `__block ASIHTTPRequest *blockRequest = self.request;` and then reference `blockRequest`. The issue being that you need to ensure that when your block runs the request hasn't been deallocated.